# What kind of string/URL encoding is this?

Tags: url, encoding

Given a sample input string of

```
ABCDabcd_1234_!_@_#_$_%_^_&_*_(_)_+
```

I see output of

```
ABCDabcd_1234_!_@040_@023_$_@025_^_@026_*_@028_@029_@02b
```

I need to be able to reproduce it, but the first step is to identify what it actually is. It looks similar to URL encoding (and it is used when form data is passed to the server) with some differences. The content type in the request header just says `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just unicode. A character is encoded as either itself, or an `"@0"` plus the unicode unit for that character, with some unknown logic for whether to encode or not. The [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) just means that the form's values are encoded as key-value pairs, with key and value separated by `=`, and pairs separated by `&`.

If you can't find any documentation on this encoding at all, you could figure out which characters get encoded by trying them all, and then reproduce it in javascript like this:

```
function encode(str) {
  let encodedString = '';
  const encodeThese = ['@', '#', '%', '&', '(', ')', '+'];

  for (char of str) {
    if (encodeThese.includes(char)) {
      encodedString = encodedString.concat('@0'.concat(char.charCodeAt()
                                                           .toString(16)));
    } else {
      encodedString = encodedString.concat(char);
    }
  }
  return encodedString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I ended up doing. I'm a bit wary of potentially missing some characters, but it's not critical so it'll do.